# template parameter constraints make more general type test fail

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, class-template

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>

template<std::integral... Is>
using arithmetic_tuple = std::tuple<Is...>;

template<typename T, template<typename...> typename U>
struct is_instance_of : std::false_type {};
template<typename... Ts, template<typename...> typename U>
struct is_instance_of<U<Ts...>, U> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};
template<typename... Ts>
struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_arithmetic_tuple : std::false_type {};
template<typename... Ts>
struct is_arithmetic_tuple<arithmetic_tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(is_tuple<arithmetic_tuple<int>>::value); // OK
static_assert(is_arithmetic_tuple<arithmetic_tuple<int>>::value); // OK
static_assert(is_instance_of<arithmetic_tuple<int>, arithmetic_tuple>::value); // fails

int main() {}
```

You can run test here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce8ae52a1d4918ba

I have write a meta function `is_instance_of` to check a type is a instantiated type of class template.

And, I have defined a `arithmetic_tuple` with `std::integral` constraints.
`is_instance_of<arithmetic_tuple<int>, arithmetic_tuple>::value` is `fales`.
However, with more specific meta function `is_tuple<arithmetic_tuple<int>>::value` and `is_arithmetic_tuple<arithmetic_tuple<int>>::value` are `true`.

At a glance, at least `is_arithmetic_tuple<arithmetic_tuple<int>>::value` should be identical with `is_instance_of<arithmetic_tuple<int>, arithmetic_tuple>::value` semantically.

Why does `is_instance_of` test here fail?
And, Can I make it works without more specific type test such as `is_tuple`?

Comment: *"should be identical"* You use `std::tuple` in `is_tuple`, but `arithmetic_tuple` in `is_instance_of`. If you pass `std::tuple` to the latter, it works. I'm not sure what's the correct behavior here though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Now I can see the difference and I have updated the question to add `is_arithmetic_tuple<T>` which I think identical with `is_instance_of<T, arithmetic_tuple>`. Thank you.

Comment: `arithmetic_tuple` *is* a different template. All of its specialisations are equivalent to `std::tuple` specialisations, but it's another template still. It's how it worked since C++11. And so far it seems intentional.

Comment: What you're trying to figure out here is that `tuple<int>` is an instance of `tuple<>` (i.e. tuple without parameters), which obviously doesn't work. is_instances_of tries to check that `arithmetic_type<int>` (which is `tuple<int>`) is instance of `arithmetic_tuple (which is `tuple<>`, not `tuple`). Using an alias breaks literally everything

Answer (score 0):

You can't deduce against an alias template. An alias template, even if written in the form you have, does not given an alias to a template itself. It is instead itself an independent template with each specialization being an alias for a type and these individual type aliases need not be in any way related through e.g. the same class template.

When the compiler comes to the point of choosing the partial specialization for `is_instance_of` in `is_instance_of<arithmetic_tuple<int>, arithmetic_tuple>`, the alias `arithmetic_tuple<int>` has already been resolved to the type `std::tuple<int>`.

Then when looking at your partial specialization which has `U` as the alias template `arithmetic_tuple` the compiler has no way of figuring out which potential `Ts...` would result in `arithmetic_tuple<Ts...>` being the same type as `std::tuple<int>`, because an alias template can map any list of template arguments to any type completely arbitrary. So such a deduction is not allowed. The partial specialization is considered to not match.

If you use

```
is_instance_of<arithmetic_tuple<int>, std::tuple>
```

instead, it will work as you expect, because `std::tuple` is the actual class template of which the type aliased by `arithmetic_tuple<int>` is a specialization.

The constraints on your alias template don't matter. The result will be the same without them.

---

Because the mapping of types via the alias is arbitrary, you can't in general write the trait how you seem to intent it. However, with the apriori assumption that the alias template does nothing more than forward the argument list, possibly constrained, to a class template, then you could do:

```
template<typename... Ts, template<typename...> typename U, template<typename...> typename V>
requires std::same_as<V<Ts...>, U<Ts...>>
struct is_instance_of<V<Ts...>, U> : std::true_type {};
```

It deduces the class template `V` independently of the passed template template argument for `U` and instead checks afterwards if the template argument list of the type would be allowed in `U` and result in the same type. If the assumption is not satisfied this will result in non-sense though.